Halacha of a railing with staircases מעקה
Imagine a studio with a loft bed that is accessed with a staircase. Does the mitzvah of a railing, מעקה, apply to staircase?

According to Sefer haBayis by R' Yosef Yitzchok Lerner (English translation also exists), section 7 halakha 23 for other places which require the guardrail:

A Ramp or staircase that are higher than 10 tefachim from the ground require a guardrail, although one does not recite a blessing over it.

This is based on Sh"A Ch"M 427:7:

Both a roof or anything dangerous where it's probable that someone will stumble upon and fall, for example if there was a well or a hole in his yard, whether there is water in it or not, one is obligated to make an embankment ten-handbreadths high, or to cover it, lest a person fall into it and die.

The Aharonim are divided concerning a ramp and stairs. Since a person is careful ascending a ramp and stairs Hagaos Maimoniyos (hilkhos Rotzeyach 11:2), Rabbeinu Yerucham (51:5) quote Sifri that ramp is exempt, Chazon Ish (Ch"M Likutim 18:5) concurs. However, Rabbeinu Yonah (Sefer haYirah 277) - a person should not have stairs in his house without a railing (he understands Sifri as not exempting ramps from railing except the railing of the altar in Beis haMikdash). This view is shared by Rabbeinu Hillel (Sifri, Ki Teitze), Magen Avraham (Zayis Ra'anan, Ki Teitze 15), Minchas Chinukh (KOmetz Mincha 546).
Chayei Adam (15:24) requires a guardrail, S'dei Chemed (klalim, 40:195, U'bameh shekatav) explains that even a wide staircase requires a rail, and certinly if narrow, since many people climb up and down, even small children, who are incapable of watching themselves.
Responsa Machazeh Eliyahu 122:17 explains the Chayei Adam that we are concerned that a person may fall from the upper landing of the staircase, since people are usually careful when climbing stairs but once they reach the landing they forget to pay attention. Where the landing gapes over the staircase, a guardrail must be made around it (if the staircase is not 4 amos by 4 amos) and the stairs too without reciting a blessing. Same view Beis Borukh (25:39), Responsa Betzel haChokhmah (4:115), Kuntres Chikrei Halakhos V'halikhos Shekhenim 29, Responsa Machazeh ELiyahu 122:6 who quotes R' Eliyashiv, same rulling is in Mishna Halakhos (second ed., vol 2, Ch"M 466).
